# In which way are HTML comment tags required?

Tags: html

Due to the header configuration in my Emacs setup, I could not autoinsert closing tags for HTML comments with the same indentation (It reads the filename, which differents in the length). So I'm wondering, for example, I have the following header:

```
<!-- foobar.html
<!-- Author: Myself
<!-- --------------- -->
```

I know this is not an elegant solution. It would be ideal if the comments on Line 1 and 2 gets closed with `-->`. But I'm doing that only on the line 3.

So I'm wondering if this would "accepted" by the browser as valid HTML syntax?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to try it in a couple of different browsers.

Comment: Having said that, browsers tend to be generous about "accepting" malformed HTML, even if the HTML would not pass a validator.

Comment: Browsers will never accept it as valid because it's not but they will guess at your intent. Never rely on browsers guessing your intent or reading your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**8.1.6 Comments**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments)
>
> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN
>   SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS (`<!--`). Following this sequence, the comment may have
>   [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-text), with the additional restriction that the text must not
>   start with a single ">" (U+003E) character, nor start with a U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) followed by a ">" (U+003E) character, nor
>   contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (`--`), nor end
>   with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-). Finally, the comment must be
>   ended by the three character sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D
>   HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (`-->`).

Since you use `--` inside the comment, your code is invalid.

However, it should be parsed like you want:

- The first `-` inside the [comment state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comment-state) will switch to the [comment end dash state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comment-end-dash-state)
- The second `-` will switch to the [comment end state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comment-end-state)
- But then you don't close the comment. Therefore,

  > [Parse error](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parse-error). Append two "-" (U+002D) characters and the [current
  >   input character](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#current-input-character) to the comment token's data. Switch to the
  >   [comment state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comment-state).

Therefore, there will be a single comment (not 3) that will contain

```
 foobar.html
<!-- Author: Myself
<!-- ---------------
```

Comment: Yes. I know it's invalid. But I'm wondering if I could use it right anyway in HTML files without that it spoils the contents below the header?

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid HTML syntax (under current rules consecutive hyphens are forbidden except at the start and end).

Modern browsers will error recover from it gracefully.

Some older browsers (which predate the common error handling rules in HTML 5) will not.

Comment: Even when it's not valid HTML syntax, if I'm understand you right: I could use it right anyway in HTML files without that it spoils the contents below the header?